# Why isn't my matplotlib pie chart saving as a png image properly?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, graph, png

Here is an image of my code:
[image]

When I open my file explorer and try to view this image only a plain white image is displayed:

[image]

You can see that my bar chart images have saved just fine, so I'm a bit confused as to why the pie charts aren't viewable.

Anyone know what the problem might be??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must write like this:

```py
plt.savefig("Visualsations/plot2.png",dpi=300) 
         
plt.show()
```

Save the figure first, and then use `plt.show()` to show it. The order matters; always check it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not completely sure if this is the solution but perhaps try and remove the bit where it says `plt.show()`. I think this might be preventing the image from saving.